# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' ... on line 87

Tags: php, error-handling

My problem is this,the problem I checked more time but not found the problem,why give me this error.

```
$i=0;
    while(count($profile->vehicles)>=$i)
    {
    echo '
    <div class="name col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <h3>'.$profile->vehicles['cars'][$i]['name'].'</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="post_date col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            <h3>'.date("d/m/Y", strtotime($profile->vehicles['cars'][$i]['post_date']).'</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="views col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            <h3>Views:<span>'.$profile->vehicles['cars'][$i]['views'].'</span></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="edit col-md-2 col-lg-2">
            <h3><a href="?page=profile&parent=edit&id='.$profile->vehicles['cars'][$i]['id'].'" >Edit</a></h3>
    </div>
';<--Here is the error
$i++;
}
```

Comment: Yes I read all,but nothing.

Comment: Close `)` in `date` function

Comment: Thx. Problem is solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved.

```
<h3>'.date("d/m/Y", strtotime($profile->vehicles['cars'][$i]['post_date'])).'</h3>
```